# Firefox remote debugging 'listen' command gives 'SyntaxError: missing ; before statement'

Tags: debugging, firefox, angular, webstorm, firefox-developer-tools

I'd like to develop AngularJS 2 web pages with Firefox + WebStorm on Windows.

For that, the [WebStorm configuration manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/debugging-javascript.html#d300360e167) tells to type `listen 6000` at the Console command line. Though doing so gives a `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` error message. `listen 6000;` does not help.

I suspect the `listen` command might be removed, as it gives `ReferenceError: listen is not defined` when executing it without port.

Of course, I already ticked the "Enable remote debugging" checkbox and restarted the browser.

Note that I'm using Firefox 49.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command line shown in the WebStorm documentation is the so called ["Developer Toolbar"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI), **not** the command line of the DevTools *Console* panel.

To open that toolbar press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> or click the Firefox menu and choose *Developer* > *Developer Toolbar*.

When you enter `listen 6000` in there, you should get a message 'Listening on port 6000' as confirmation that it was successfully executed.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, as WebStorm stopped supporting Firefox Remote Debugger, and Firefox Quantum moved the place where you start the listener to `about:debugging#/setup`